# Can't pass parameters in Django, giving MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have gone through answers of this type of question but they don't seem relevant for my problem.

I have a class defined as follows:

```
class TrainModel(APIView):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

def post(self, request, *args):
    print("I am here")
    params = json.loads(request.POST["params"])
    print(params)
    #setup_instance.apply_async((params,), queue="local")
    fit_model(params, "")
    model_name = "{}-{}-{}-{}".format(
        params["match_slug"], params["match_id"], params["model_type"], params["version"])
    response = {
        "success": True,
        "message": "Model is being trained please wait",
        "data": {"model_name": model_name}
    }
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

It also requires other inputs:

`params["meta"]["xgb"]` 
`params["combined"]`

And I pass them as follows:

```html
import requests
import json

headers = {'Authorization': 'Token $TOKEN', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
url = 'http://somesite.com/train/'

params = {  "match_id": 14142,
            "model_type": "xgb",
            "version": "v2",
            "match_slug": "csk-vs-kkr-26-mar-2022",
            "meta": {
                "xgb": {
                    "alpha": 15,
                    "max_depth": 4,
                    "objective": "reg:linear",
                    "n_estimators": 53,
                    "random_state": 0,
                    "learning_rate": 0.1,
                    "colsample_bytree": 0.4
                },
                "catboost": {
                    "cat_cols": [
                        "batting order_lag_1",
                        "venue",
                        "against",
                        "role",
                        "bowlType"
                    ],
                    "eval_metric": "RMSE",
                    "random_seed": 42,
                    "logging_level": "Silent",
                    "loss_function": "RMSE"
                }
            },
            "image_id": "SOME_ID",
            "combined": 0
        }

resp = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers)

print(resp)
```

I try the same in Postman by putting all these parameters in "Body" (using "raw") but get:

```
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value: 'params'
```

Need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
class TrainModel(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data # I would suggest using a serializer and it automatically validates your data 

        fit_model(data, "")
        model_name = "{}-{}-{}-{}".format(
            data.get("match_slug"), data.get("match_id"), data.get("model_type"), data.get("version"))

        response = {
            "success": True,
            "message": "Model is being trained please wait",
            "data": {"model_name": model_name}
        }

        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! Could you help me understand what happened here or point to sources to read. I will have to read up on serializer too....

Comment: This links might help
- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#request-parsing
- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances
- https://github.com/MohamedAliHamza/DoctorOnline/blob/main/user/api/admin/views.py